# Angular 5 material design full-width inputs

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, material-design, angular5

I'm new to angular 5, so I need to make a form with full-width inputs, and I want to every input take the whole width of its container, however, it only takes up half of it.

Here is [what I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qCDO.png)

I'm using angular material 
and here is my code:

```
<mat-grid-tile class="add-product-content" [rowspan]="4">
    <form [formGroup]="addProductGroup" class="form-add-product" (ngSubmit)="sendDataProduct()">
        <mat-accordion >
            <mat-expansion-panel [expanded]="step === 0" (opened)="setStep(0)" >
              <mat-expansion-panel-header>
                <mat-panel-title>Personal data</mat-panel-title>
              </mat-expansion-panel-header>
              <div class="input-container">
                  <div class="flex-item">
                      <mat-form-field>
                          <input matInput placeholder="First name">
                      </mat-form-field>
                  </div>
                  <div class="flex-item">
                      <mat-form-field>
                        <input matInput type="number" min="1" placeholder="Age">
                      </mat-form-field>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <mat-action-row>
                  <button mat-button color="primary" (click)="nextStep()">Next</button>
              </mat-action-row>
           </mat-expansion-panel>

           <mat-expansion-panel [expanded]="step === 1" (opened)="setStep(1)" >
              <mat-expansion-panel-header>
                  <mat-panel-title>Personal data</mat-panel-title>
              </mat-expansion-panel-header>

              <mat-form-field>
                  <input matInput placeholder="First name">
              </mat-form-field>
              <mat-form-field>
                  <input matInput type="number" min="1" placeholder="Age">
              </mat-form-field>
              <mat-action-row>
                  <button mat-button color="warn" (click)="prevStep()">Previous</button>
                  <button mat-button color="primary" (click)="nextStep()">Next</button>
              </mat-action-row>
          </mat-expansion-panel>
      </mat-accordion>
      <button mat-raised-button type="submit" class="actionButton">add</button>
    </form>
</mat-grid-tile>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

On all of your `mat-form-field`, you will need to add a class which you can call what you want but I'll call it `full-width-field` so, in the end, it will look like this.

**HTML:**

```html
<mat-form-field class="full-width-field">
  <input matInput type="number" min="1" placeholder="Age">
</mat-form-field>
```

**CSS:**

```css
.full-width-field {
   width: 100%;
}
```

Example take from [Angular Material Docs](https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview)

Answer (score 3):

You have to apply your custom style to make all mat-form-field to full-width:

```
mat-form-field{
    width: 100%;
}
```

Automatically **all** material input elements inside it will have full-width

Answer (score 0):

Although the answers suggesting using `width:100%` will work, they will also mean you need to think a little bit more carefully about margins as depending on your box-model you could find that you have widths even larger than the surrounding container.

A a more inert change is just to change the styling of the `mat-form-field` from `inline-block` (its default) to block

**HTML:**

```
<mat-form-field class="full-width-field">
  <input matInput type="number" min="1" placeholder="Age">
</mat-form-field>
```

**CSS:**

```
.full-width-field {
  display: block;
}
```